Close the application B and return to application A
I am building an app  using kotlin in android studio which is mainly used to scan the QR code. Once the QR code is scanned successfully then clicking on  proceed to pay will open the clover sales app . After the transaction is completed in the sales app . I want to close the clover sales app(programmatically) and return to my app.
I am able to open the clover sales app using intend(the code is attached below). But, I don't know how to close the clover sales app(programmatically) and return to my app .
So, Could anyone please guide me how to achieve that?
Do anyone have any idea of how can I be sure to go back to application A when application B is over ?
`
   private fun openCloverSalesApp(amountInCents: Long) {
     val packageManager: PackageManager = packageManager 
    val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(CLOVER_SALES_PACKAGE) 
    if (intent != null) {
        try {
            intent.putExtra("CustomerId", customerId.toString())
            intent.putExtra(Intents.EXTRA_AMOUNT, amountInCents) 

       // Launch the Clover Sales app
            startActivity(intent)

        
    } else {
        // Show an error message if the Clover Sales app is not installed
        Log.e("CloverSales", "Clover Sales app not found")
    }
}`


One workaround might be using startActivityForResult instead of launching the application itself:
private fun openCloverSalesApp(amountInCents: Long) {
    val packageManager: PackageManager = packageManager 
    val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(CLOVER_SALES_PACKAGE)
    if (intent != null) {
        intent.putExtra("CustomerId", customerId.toString())
        intent.putExtra(Intents.EXTRA_AMOUNT, amountInCents)

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CLOVER_SALES)
    } else {
        Log.e("CloverSales", "Clover Sales app not found")
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CLOVER_SALES) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //transaction successful scenario, so do your task here
        }
    }
}


That will only work if the Clover app closes itself.  If it doesn't, startActivityForResult won't force it to finish.  (Also startActivityForResult is deprecated, but the replacement would have the same problem).

In general there is no way to force another app to finish their Activity.  Not even if you launch it.  You'd need the Clover developers to have coded their app to do so.
However in this specific case-  Clover has a lot of APIs you can call that may be better suited for what you want to do.  See https://docs.clover.com/docs/intents-and-broadcasts# for their documentation.  In particular, the ACTION_CLOVER_PAY intent seems like it would be what you want to use.  And since it's an intent that returns a result, that means the activity probably plans on finishing.
